# What command line to delete folder in Appdata folder for local user?

Tags: powershell, command-line

I am trying to test a script to delete a folder in APPdata local folder for a user on machine but testing it locally on my test machine.  i cannot use the %userprofile% so technically need to delete a test folder at c:/users/testusername/appdata/local/test

Whats the correct command to delete folders or files from a local user account? I don't want to use the exact name of user.

Also for power shell if i want to delete folders that begin with test_foldername is there a way i can wild card to delete anything with "test_"?

Thanks

Comment: `$env:APPDATA`  or `$env:LOCALAPPDATA` Delete: `Remove-Item`

Comment: @jrider - you should specify that your varname and command are for PowerShell, as contrasted with "the command line" (CMD.EXE).

Comment: i need it to point to local user who is on the machine

Answer (score 2):

Ended up using the following

```
$users = Get-ChildItem C:\Users
foreach ($user in $users){$folder = "$($user.fullname)\AppData\Local\Test"
```

`If (Test-Path $folder) {Remove-Item $folder -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction` `silentlycontinue } }`

Answer (score 0):

`Get-Childitem -Directory -Path $env:LOCALAPPDATA | where {$_.Name -like 'test_*'} | Remove-Item -Force -Recurse -WhatIf`

Remove the `-WhatIf` to actual perform the delete

`$env:LOCALAPPDATA` will refer to the oaming app data location for the user running the script